# pyMC3 - Using the value of a variable

Tags: python, bayesian, montecarlo, pymc3, pymc

I am simulating a very basic Bayesian Network using pyMC3. In this simulation, I have only categorical variables. Given the value of a variable, I would like to set the distribution of another variable based on output from a Pandas Dataframe that I have used to store conditional probabilities. For example, if `x` is a pyMC3  random variable, and `x=1` in an instance of the simulation, then I would like to access `p_y_cond_x.loc[x]`, which in this instance is just `p_y_cond_x.loc[1]`, with here `p_y_cond_x` is a  pre-computed (using data) conditional probability table stored as a pandas series.

Is there any easy way to do this? Unfortunately `x` is not an integer when instantiating the model (say, using a `with` block), so I'm not sure how I could access its value and do the above when the simulation is running.

I have seen solutions using `pm.math.switch`, but unfortunately my variables are ternary so I will need to use two switches for each conditional. Moreover, if I need to condition on multiple variables I imagine this will be painful.

Comment: Maybe try applying [`theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot`](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/tensor/extra_ops.html#theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot) to `x` which will expand it to a matrix, then you can multiply that matrix with the `p_y_cond_x` vector to yield the corresponding vector you are trying to get. There may be more efficient approaches - kind of depends on whether the one-hot encoding matrix is sparse or not (IDK).

Answer (score 1):

Using pyAgrum, you could use the notation `bn.cpt("Y")[{"X":1}]`.

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I will take a look at this package. Thanks very much!